# ''rvm requirements'" is failing because of apt-get... WUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, vmware

I just want to install Ruby-on-Rails on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit running inside VMWare in a Windows 8 environment.

I am following the following steps:

```
1. Install RVM multi-user

\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
adduser yourusername rvm
rvm requirements
install the requirements given
log out and back in
add source command to ~/.bash.rc

2. Install ruby and rails and others

rvm install 1.9.3
rvm rubygems current
gem install rails
sudo apt-get install nodejs

3. Does rails work?

cd ~
mkdir rails
cd rails
START DEVELOPING!

useful commands:
bundle install -- install the gems needed for this app
bundle exec rails server -- run the server!
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

but on the 3rd step I get the following:

```
mattnificent@UbuntuVMWare:~$ rvm requirements
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system.................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ',
showing last 15 lines of /home/mattnificent/.rvm/log/1410125635/update_system.log
+ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
+ case "$1" in
+ [[ -t 2 ]]
+ return 1
+ printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

+ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Can anyone tell me what the hell is going on?

ELI5.

Thanks.

Comment: No need to install nodejs. Add the 'execjs' gem and you are good to go.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use a multi-user install?

Comment: I have no reason to install multi-user install. I don't even car about rvm. I just want Ruby.

Comment: Ok, I just installed Ruby using rbenv following the instructions on this website: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04#ruby-rvm